# Linux Mint 18.1 Reset forgotten Admin password when I remember the root password

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 18.1 that's encrypted on a laptop, but I remember the password to unencrypt the hard drive and the root password, but I forget the password to my admin account. However I know in the GUI of Linux Mint it won't let you log into root.

So how would I go about resetting the password for my admin account when I know the password for root? Any way to bypass the GUI and enter the terminal to temporarily log into root to reset the admin password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `root` password is not locked (as you make sound it):

Open a terminal and run `su` - enter the `root` password. Now as the root user, you can change any password with `passwd USER`, where `USER` is you admin user's login name.

If you cannot log in into any graphical interface, use `CRTL+ALT+F1`, to drop to a CLI. There log in as `root` and use `passwd` as above. Return to the graphical tty with `CTRL+ALT+F7`. (and use `exit` to log out for safety reasons)